# Will Unity 7.3.1 be backported to 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, unity

I'm wondering if we will see the Unity 7.3.1 release backported to 14.04 LTS release? I wanted to stick to the LTS right now, but with the HiDPI fixes I may have to upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Unity 7.3.1 will not be backported to 14.04.

The good news is that, with the exception of changes made to build or run with newer versions of software in Ubuntu 14.10 (for example, compiling under GCC 4.9 instead of GCC 4.8, newer GTK+ libraries, etc.), almost all bugfixes have been backported to Unity 7.2 and [SRU'd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) into 14.04.  There are no bugfixes for high-DPI that appear in 14.10 that have not been (or are not being) backported to 14.04.  We expect that to continue in the Vivid cycle.

The [SRU](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) process is a little slow:  fixed need to land in the current Ubuntu development version first and be tested, then a careful process of verification and validation must be followed before the change appears in 14.04.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure what was back-ported. This makes my decision way easier.

Answer (score 1):

Unity 7.3.1 has been ported to Ubuntu 14.04 by Doug McMahon (the person who is responsible for maintaining the Multimedia for Trusty PPA) in its PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-prop